# How to add the inline styles in SharePoint 2013 after migration from SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013, when we attach an item, this is how the edit page is displayed.
[image].
The complete image was not being displayed. On inspecting the page, and making modifications at 2 classes,
[image].In this image, height was changed from 236px to 357px. 
[image].

In the below image the height was changed from 172px to 285px.\
[image].

Then we are getting the edit form in proper format in browser level.
[image].

Can anyone help me on how to make the changes of Inline styles in SharePoint 2013, as I am not able to add the html code in Content Editor webpart as a separate dialogue box is getting opened for the attachments. And the way this attachments page is displayed is common in 10 such lists.

Can you provide with a common way of changing the code at one place, so that all the list page attachments are displayed normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override CSS with !important.

Demo:

```
<style>
.ms-dlgFrame{
height:285px !important;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Update:

Try to filter based on pageType, 8 for new form when I test in my local.

```
.ms-dlgFrame[src*="PageType=8"] { 
  height:285px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes , This is working. But the remaining views like Edit and View are also getting changed according to those dimensions. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try my update..

Answer (score 0):

So you will need to edit the form pages of your list, to do so, follow the following steps:

- Open SharePoint Designer
- On the left menu, select "All Files"
- Select the folder "Lists"
- Select the desired List
- You will be able to see all form files.

[image: Example]

- Edit and add your code on NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx

PS: Do not forget to checkout before editing.

It should work

Comment: We do not use SharePoint designer for our project